# Heroku csv gem not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I put in my gemfile
gem 'csv'
because I use csv in my code.

When I run locally everything is fine.

However, when I push it to heroku (which worked previously), the whole thing crashes and I get an error that a csv gem could not be found.

However, when I remove it, everything works including the code involving the CSV.

Is it fine to just omit it?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a part of core Ruby in 1.9.3.  It no longer requires a gem to use the functionality.

See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html